What is query generation re-ranking method?
I am reading up on reranking methodologies that leverage LLMs. Relevant literature.
One of the methods suggested is query generation

Or, the same methodology from another source

The task is to rank the passages according to their relevance to a given passage
Here they suggest giving the LLM the context and asking it to generate a query. How does this help rank the contexts as per their relevance to the given query? We generate a query given all the contexts.. Now what?
